# Reading iphone messages inbox in my app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a problem in reading iphone messages inbox in my app,and i used this code :

```
- (IBAction) read{

    NSString *text = @"";

    sqlite3 *database;
    if(sqlite3_open([@"/var/root/Library/SMS/sms.db" UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;

        const char *sql4 = "SELECT * from message ORDER BY rowid DESC";  // TODO: different for iOS 4.* ???
        const char *sql5 = "SELECT * from message ORDER BY rowid DESC";

        NSString *osVersion =[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];         
        if([osVersion hasPrefix:@"5"]) {
            // iOS 5.* -> tested
           sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql5, -1, &statement, NULL);
        } else {
            // iOS != 5.* -> untested!!!
            sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql4, -1, &statement, NULL);
        }

        // Use the while loop if you want more than just the most recent message
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                char *content = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
                text = [NSString stringWithCString: content encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            }
        }

        sqlite3_close(database);
    }

    showsms.text=text;
    NSLog(@"test");
}
```

but i cant access the "SMS.DB", i have searched on the internet but no one have a problem like this,  plz  anyone have any idea about my issue write my the code or tell me his way.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The app sandbox doesn't allow you to access that file. Even if you did get it to work, Apple wouldn't allow it in the store.