# My APP want get the message from SMS Inbox, how to do that

Tags: ios, swift, sms, google-glass, aero-glass

My APP (In IOS platform) want get the message from SMS Inbox,  how to do that? I also know that Google Glass APP can do that in iphone. How to get the message from SMS inbox in swift? thanks very much.

Comment: in a regular environment you cannot do it because there no official API for it which would pass the review procedure, otherwise if you are not targeting to distribute your app via AppStore it may be possible.

Comment: my APP is not target for APP Store, so could you tell me the detail method, thanks in advance

Comment: that post may help on you to start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25262064/read-sms-db-and-call-history-db-file-on-ios

Comment: iOS 12 Update 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextcontenttype/2980930-onetimecode

Answer (score 2):

You can not acces the SMS inbox on iOS, there is **no** API for it in the Public iOS SDK. What Google Glass does is handle the notification of incoming message via the Bluetooth Profile, this not something you can do in an app.

Comment: Thanks for your message. Google Glass (device) using Bluetooth communicate with iPhone, but its APP should first retrieve the SMS inbox content, then send to the Glass through Bluetooth. if Google Glass app can be authorized to access the SMS inbox, any other APP should also has the permissions ,That's my guess.

Comment: No, the Google Glass app does not read the SMS inbox. The bluetooth protocol has a special protocol for displaying messages, this is wat google glass is using. This is also what some smartwacthes use.

Answer (score 1):

We don't have any public API to get access SMS at the moment. Sorry to say this but it is practically impossible with public API as of now.

Comment: Thanks for your message, do you know which  private function should be used in swift?